# Drawing points using SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I want to draw some points by giving their x y coordinates using SFML. Is there a specific SFML function (for instance, to draw a circle `sf::CircleShape` function is used) to draw points or it is done in a different way?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "points"?

Answer (score 4):

Looking through the documentation I think you should use [this](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1RenderTarget.php#a976bc94057799eb9f8a18ac5fdfd9b73).

```
sf::Vertex point(sf::Vector2f(10, 10), sf::Color::Black);
window.draw(&point, 1, sf::Points);
```

`window` is a `sf::RenderTarget`.

Comment: And to draw multiple points, you should use a ```sf::VertexArray```